# Can we not initialize reference array in Trie constructor

Tags: java, data-structures, trie

In [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/) Trie implementation, `children` array elements are assigned `null` value individually using a `for` loop.

```
TrieNode(){ 
    isEndOfWord = false; 
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++) 
    children[i] = null; 
}
```

However, by default, when we create an array of reference types in Java, all entries will have default value as `null` which is:

```
TrieNode[] children = new TrieNode[ALPHABET_SIZE];
```

The above step assigns default values of `children` array entries as `null`.

Is it required to have `null` assignment once again in the `for` loop inside that  `TrieNode` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No it's not required** - for each class variable, instance variable, or array component Java will always assign reasonable default value (like `0` for `int` or null for `Object`) - you can read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

However notice that for local variables it's not [guaranteed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variablesummary.html)

> The compiler will assign a reasonable default value for fields of the above types; for local variables, a default value is never assigned.

and that's why you are forced to initialize it manually

```
public void f() {
    String s;
    System.out.println(s); // will cause Error: java: variable s might not have been initialized
}
```